Reason for avoiding implicit IO in attribute access in SQLAlchemy 2.0 asyncio
I am refering to this part of the SQLAlchemy 2.0 documentation that mentions that implicit IO on attribute access which are lazy-loaded (i.e. relationships) should be prevented, in favour of using eager-loading or using awaitable attrs.
I am curious to know what are the technical reasons for such a constraint? Can't they enqueue a new task for the additional SELECT operation?
I couldn't find a detailed explanation in the docs so would appreciate it if anyone could clarify this for me.
